# Ubuntu 10.04 failed to upgrade with Command terminated with exit status 1

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

I have old Ubuntu 10.04. It has been 5 years ago. I want to update it.
But I cannot success to upgrade it. Does anyone know about this problem.
I have tried a couple days to fix it. Thanks a lot

[image: Update Manager Err]

```
x11proto-core-dev 
x11proto-input-dev 
x11proto-randr-dev 
x11proto-xext-dev 
xdiagnose 
xkb-data 
xorg 
xserver-common 
xserver-xorg 
xserver-xorg-core 
xserver-xorg-input-all 
xserver-xorg-input-evdev 
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse 
xserver-xorg-input-wacom 
xserver-xorg-video-all 
xserver-xorg-video-intel 
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome 
xserver-xorg-video-qxl 
xserver-xorg-video-vmware 
xsettings-kde 
xsltproc 
xterm 
xul-ext-ubufox 
zeitgeist 
zeitgeist-core 
zenity 
zenity-common 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
=== Command detached from window (Tue Oct 20 09:33:50 2015) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Tue Oct 20 09:33:50 2015) ===
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades

Comment: Thanks @mchid. I have done to do this tutorial before but it does not work for me.

Comment: @p-h-line Thanks. I have read it but I do not find button upgrade in update manager box. Any suggestion?